# Sorting glob qualifiers do nothing in zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, glob

I want to use the glob qualifiers in zsh to sort files by various criteria. For example, `ls -l *(.oL)` is supposed to return ordinary files sorted by size.

Everything else in zsh seems to work as advertised, but the sorting operators `o` and `O` have no effect. The results are always sorted by filename.

I’ve tried removing my `.zshrc` file, but that did not fix this.

I’m on Debian 11 and installed zsh from the repository, getting me v. 5.8.

Comment: Are you sure `ls` isn't doing its own sorting?

Comment: ...you can use `set -x` to tell the shell to log the arguments it passes to `ls`, and compare their order to the order of `ls`'s output.

Comment: Or just change to `printf '%s\n' *(.oL)` and see if _that_ sorts the way you expect.

Comment: Not the same issue, but I think [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694823/why-do-zsh-parameter-expansion-flags-not-work-with-here-strings) shows why this isn't working, but @CharlesDuffy's way is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charles Duffy is correct, it is `ls` that is re-sorting the files alphabetically. We can see this using his suggestions or simply by using `echo`.

`ls` has its own sorting flags, but I wanted to commit just one syntax to memory. Filename sorting in ls can be disabled with the `-U` flag.

It’s odd, because several popular guides to zsh that I consulted all use sorting examples with `ls`. Has `ls` changed its behavior recently? Is the version distributed with Debian unusual?

Comment: Whatever guide you're looking at is probably just wrong.

Comment: When you just want filenames that match a glob pattern, `ls` is usually the wrong approach.

Comment: `ls` would be pointless for just listing the filenames, but I wanted to use the long version (actually using `exa`) to see a grid of file properties. `exa` also sorts by filename, and it can also be turned off.

Comment: `ls` isn't a standard part of zsh -- it's provided by your operating system, so the version you have is different between GNU Linux, vs embedded Linux using busybox, vs MacOS, vs HPUX, etc. You can't really expect that a person writing a tutorial will have the same `ls` implementation you have.

Comment: [The POSIX standard for `ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/ls.html) _does_ direct it to do its own sorting when it's passed a directory name (or with just bare `ls` defaulting to `ls .`, so listing a directory). It's not obvious to me at a quick glance if there's standard-mandated behavior when all items are explicitly provided; if the standard doesn't mandate something, then each implementation can be different.

Comment: To me it seems odd zsh behaviour, because (.Lm+n), (.Lk+n), and (.Lp+n) seem to works  but doesn't when combined with o or O. For example m attribute as in (.oLm+n) does not perform any sorting, k size attribute is not recognised while, p attribute gives no matches